# Function calls in logging configuration file

Tags: python, logging

I had the following logging configuration in code that I now want to set through a configuration file.

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%s:'%getpass.getuser() + '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s')
```

In the configuration file, I have

```
>     [formatter_frmtr]
>     format=getpass.getuser() + '%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s:%(module)s:%(lineno)d:%(message)s'
```

The function call getpass.getuser() is not getting called but is printed as is:

> getpass.getuser() + '2011-06-01
>   11:56:53,924:ERROR:test:7:test'

How do I make get the username of the callee through the logging config file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the techniques described in the [logging documentation](http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#adding-contextual-information-to-your-logging-output) to add additional cobtext to your logging messages.